# Is there any difference regarding performance of private, protected, public and internal methods in C# classes?

Tags: c#, performance, class, methods, members

Is there any difference regarding performance of `private`, `protected`, `public` and `internal` methods in C# class? I'm interested if one consumes more processor time or RAM.

Comment: microptimisation anyone?

Comment: Probably not, but there is a improvement (memory, I think) with sealed classes.

Comment: What about `private static` (as opposed to non-`static`) methods?

Comment: @Jonathan Dickinson: I'd expect it to be a potential virtual member optimization, where the JIT compiler *knows* that even a virtual method isn't going to be overridden any further.

Comment: @Jon there is a obfuscator that **claims** improved speed/memory, and its primary method of achieving that is sealing non-inherited internal classes (because it knows they can 'never' be subclassed) - I am not sure of the JIT specifics though.

Comment: @Richard - making methods that don't refer to `this` `static` is part of the Microsoft.Performance FXCop ruleset; so I assume it does make a difference.

Comment: Mitch Wheat: no, just was looking for similar question in the net and haven't found anything, and for C# and .NET I thought I would ask if something is going on behind the scenes when calling the methods with different access modifiers.

Comment: The only access modifiers that improve performance are *static* and *sealed*. In both cases the compiler can either skip the vtable lookup, or in the case of sealed methods/classes, take a big shortcut to the top of it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not *aware* of any performance difference for normal invocation; it's possible that more restricted access will take a little more work when accessing via dynamic invocation or reflection as the caller may need to be validated more carefully. In the normal JIT-compiled case the access can be validated by the CLR just once and then taken for granted. I guess it's possible that the JIT compilation (and IL verification) itself could be slightly slower for more restrictive access - but I find it hard to believe it would be significant.

This should *absolutely not* be a factor in determining which accessibility to use, even if somehow there is some tiny performance difference I'm unaware of. If you believe you may be able to achieve a performance benefit by making the accessibility something other than the "natural" one for your design, you should definitely benchmark the before/after case - I suspect you'll be hard-pressed to find a real-world situation where the difference is reliably measurable.

The same sort of advice goes for all kinds of micro-optimization: it's almost never a good idea anyway, and should *definitely* only be undertaken within careful measuring.

Comment: I'm surprised that you weren't more unequivocal.  Having said that, I was in the process of elaborating on "No".

Comment: wouldn't private methods perhaps be optimized (inlined, e.g.) more aggressively by the JIT engine?

Comment: @sehe: Why would you think that? Even if a method is public, it can't change after JIT compilation...

Comment: @sehe - I don't think so. It's cross-ngen boundary or not, so if you call a `public` method from the **same assembly** it will get inlined just as agressively as a `private` one; the only way to get cross-ngen-boundary inlining is with [`TargettedPatchingOptOutAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.targetedpatchingoptoutattribute.aspx).

Comment: @Jon: well, I wasn't thinking of modification (urgh?) but rather pragmatism: as soon as the compiler knows a method should be externally available, it might decide not to inline it at all in the interest of reducing code size? I was simply contemplating this, hoping you had a ready answer :)

Comment: @Jonathan: that's interesting stuff. (_However, about Targeted Patching: on reading [backgrounds](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clrcodegeneration/archive/2009/05/03/improvements-to-ngen-in-.net-framework-4.aspx) it would seem that would only apply to Framework Libraries (and we don't get to call any private methods from them anyway)_)

Comment: @sehe: I'm not *aware* of the JIT inliner taking this approach, but it's possible I guess....

Comment: @sehe: no it really does work with non-Framework Libraries; although it will increase the ngen time of any dependencies - it also only makes a difference with public methods (it basically allows them to get inlined into an ngen image for another assembly); and only does something if you ngen the assembly.

Comment: Ok, so the lowdown is: it _might_ make _teeny tiny_ bits of difference, but the chances are exceptionally small, as the JIT optimizer appears to be more aggressive (... than I would have expected for a VM-based jitter) in that public methods are eligible for inlining within assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

There will be no measurable difference in performance between private, protected or public methods. 
If you focus on optimization, possibly you should try making your bottleneck piece of code more "procedural" than object-oriented. It would do small improvement.